# How to write this sql with laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```sql
    select count('vehicules.id')
    from vehicules
      INNER JOIN (equipements, contenirs)
         ON (contenirs.vehicule_id = vehicules.id AND contenirs.equipement_id = equipements.id)
     WHERE(vehicules.KMActuel-contenirs.dernierKM > equipements.kilometrageMax);
```

That is the code that I want to execute with laravel.
I tried code like :

```php
$special = DB::select("SELECT COUNT('vehicules.id') FROM vehicules INNER JOIN (equipements, contenirs) ON (contenirs.vehicule_id = vehicules.id AND contenirs.equipement_id = equipements.id) WHERE(vehicules.KMActuel-contenirs.dernierKM > equipements.kilometrageMax)");
```

I call the variable in my view and i get an error like:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\laragon\www\GSMV\resources\views\dash.blade.php)
```

Comment: Start with writing it as proper SQL.

Comment: The sql code above work but when i tried the it doesn't work :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't execute expressions in a string you pass to regular eloquent methods. You have to use raw expressions that can be parsed accordingly:

```php
DB::table('vehicules')
    ->join('contenirs', 'vehicules.id', 'contenirs.vehicule_id') 
    ->join('equipements','equipements.id','contenirs.equipement_id') 
    ->whereRaw('vehicules.KMActuel-contenirs.dernierKM > equipements.kilometrageMax')
    ->select('vehicules.*', 'contenirs.designation')
    ->count('vehicules.id');
```

Comment: I tried but I got an error near **whereRaw('vehicules.KMActuel-contenirs.dernierKM'**

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'vehicules.KMActuel-contenirs.dernierKM' at line 1 (SQL: select count(`vehicules`.`id`) as aggregate from `vehicules` inner join `contenirs` on `vehicules`.`id` = `contenirs`.`vehicule_id` inner join `equipements` on `equipements`.`id` = `contenirs`.`equipement_id` where equipements.kilometrageMax vehicules.KMActuel-contenirs.dernierKM)

Comment: I fixed a mistake I made in that line. Maybe that'll fix your error.

Comment: With `whereRaw()`. Doesn't my fix change anything?